Как в pgAdmin4 работать с конкретной ячейкой?
У меня есть база данных, есть таблица с первой колонкой ФИО и также с первой строкой дата события, соответственно при пересечении колонки и даты ставится оценка( 5,4,3,2, но также можно поставить "Б" - болел отсутствовал, "Н" - не пришёл без причины), то есть выглядит по сути как школьный журнал, но мне нужно сделать так чтобы по каждому человеку за все даты занятий выводился средний балл, то есть формула сложить все числа и поделить на количество ячеек, не понимаю как обратиться к таким ячейкам, и тем более возможно ли это делать в pgAdmin4.

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! Stack Overflow на русском — это сайт вопросов и ответов для профессиональных разработчиков программного обеспечения, энтузиастов программирования и системных администраторов. Сайт создан и управляется сообществом. С вами вместе мы создаём свободную библиотеку подробных ответов на любой прикладной вопрос по программированию и системному администрированию. Приглашаем вас ознакомиться со справкой, как задать хороший вопрос =>https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
